# Geometry of the commutator of two rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two special orthogonal matrices, i.e. two rotations in some vector space. It is easy to imagine a rotation, at least in 3 dimensions. But I don't know how to imagine the commutator of two rotations, $ABA^TB^T$. What does this operator do to a vector, exactly? Of course it is also a rotation, but how is that rotation related to the ones performed by $A$ and $B$? Or, in other words, why should I care about the commutator? What is the geometry of it?

Comment: Does not this get you back to your starting point?

Comment: As $A$ and $B$ are in 3D usually not commutative then $AB$ and $BA$ are different rotations. $A$ and $B$ commute if they have the same axis of rotation, If they do not commute you can consider result axes of rotations $AB$ and $BA$ with formula given by Jyrki Lahtonen's answer for  [this question ][1].   Generally $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues so have the same angle of rotation, $(BA)^{−1}$ has the same axis of rotation as $BA$ but the opposite angle to $BA$.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863176/the-relation-between-axes-of-3d-rotations